# Order hybrid mixed mysql search result in one query?

Tags: sql, mysql

This problem is easy fixed clientside. But for performance I want to do it directly to the database.

```
LIST a
+------+-------+-------+
| name | score | cre   |
+------+-------+-------+
| Abe  | 3     | 1     |
| Zoe  | 5     | 2     |
| Mye  | 1     | 3     |
| Joe  | 3     | 4     |
```

Want to retrieve a joined hybrid result without duplications.

```
Zoe (1st highest score)
Joe (1st last submitted)
Abe (2nd highest score)
Mye (2nd last submitted)
...
```

Clientside i take each search by itself and step though them.
but on 100.000+ its getting awkward. To be able to use the LIMIT function would ease things up a lot!

```
SELECT name FROM a ORDER BY score DESC, cre DESC;
SELECT name FROM a ORDER BY cre DESC, score DESC;
```

Comment: Hello Fredrik, What you need exactly would you explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not provide Analytic Functions like `ROW_NUMBER`.

One way to implement this would be two queries with different `Order By`, joined together:

```
Select s.name, s.score_num, c.cre_num
From
(
    Select name, @score_num := @score_num + 1 As score_num
    From your_table, ( SELECT @score_num := 0 ) v
    Order By score Desc
) s
Join
(
    Select name, @cre_num := @cre_num + 1 As cre_num
    From your_table, ( SELECT @cre_num := 0 ) v
    Order By cre Desc
) c
On ( c.name = s.name )
```

returns

```
name  score_num  cre_num
Joe           3        1
Mye           4        2
Zoe           1        3
Abe           2        4
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, very nice solution! By joining  the data i can choice how to weight their importance. Optimal is my case was actually not the strict version but the summed one. Well done!
"SELECT [...] IF(s.score_num<c.cre_num,score_num,cre_num) strict [...] ORDER BY strict"
and my preferred:
"SELECT [...] (s.score_num+c.cre_num) sum [...] ORDER BY sum"