# php/mysql search results - filter result when type >1 while keeping results where other types not >1 - codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, search

Apologies for the title, I'm still trying to work out how to explain this.

I have a codeigniter web app that has a decent search function that nicely tabulates the results. Let's call it an airbnb clone where multiple users create listings. Users can create a single listing or they can create multiple listings.

When searching in an area, each conforming result is displayed. If a user has ten listings that are in the search results, then all ten listings are displayed. I want to limit it to a single result if a user has more than one conforming result.

Currently, the database is queried with search terms and returned to a foreach loop for each resulting row. I'm trying to figure out the best way to limit multiple results by a single user so that one user with 20 listings in the same location doesn't clog up the results.

My goal is not to prevent the searching user from finding the results, I'm just trying to control how multiple listings by a single user are displayed so as not to clutter up the search results with 10s or 100s of results from the same user in the same location. Instead of being displayed individually in the search results, I will show a general result with info on that user that will link to a page with all the listings available from that user.

Any ideas?

I can post some code when necessary, but I'm trying to work it out conceptually first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There really should be some other type of metric to determine relevance and return/display the results based on how relevant it is regardless of who posted them. I'd be pissed if I knew good results were being hidden just because they were from the same user.

Take for example baseball cards. If I were searching for "Joe Jackson" I'd rather 20 results from one user for Joe Jackson rather than 2 results for Joe Jackson, 1 result for Sam Jackson and 7 results for Bob Jackson from 5 different users.

That all said, there are some examples out there of mixing results:
[Mixing different categories results, ordered by score in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6244787/183254)
[Order hybrid mixed mysql search result in one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666952/183254)

Comment: Thanks for the response. My goal is not to prevent the searching user from finding the results, I'm just trying to control how multiple listings by a single user are displayed so as not to clutter up the search results with 10s or 100s of results from the same user in the same location. 

Instead of being displayed individually in the search results, I will show a general result with info on that user that will link to a page with all the listings available from that user.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yup, sounds like a great solution to the problem.

Comment: My problem still remains how to do it. I know what I want to do, but I'm not sure the best way to program it.

Comment: Best bet is to jump in and start trying things. If you are having a particular problem with a specific piece of code, come back and ask a question :)